# Dropzone.js replace preview image with text on successful upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I have a dropzone like this:

```
<form action="SaveAddressFile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="dropzone" id="addressFile">
    <div class="fallback">
        <input name="file" type="file" />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
     </div>
 </form>
```

What I want to happen is for when the user drops a file on it,  if the upload is successful then the icon (and the text/tick image) will be replaced with the message the server sends back.

So far I have:

```
        Dropzone.options.addressFile = {
        maxFiles: 1,
        init: function() {
            this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function(file){
                this.removeFile(file);
            });
        },
        accept: function(file, done) {
            var thumbnail = $('.dropzone .dz-preview.dz-file-preview .dz-image:last');

            switch (file.type) {

            case 'application/vnd.ms-excel':
                thumbnail.css('background', 'url(/images/fileIcons/excel.png');
                break;
            case 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet':
                thumbnail.css('background', 'url(/images/fileIcons/excel.png');
                break;
            }

            done();
        },
          success:function(file, response) {
            $('#addressFile.dropzone .dz-preview.dz-file-preview .dz-image:last').css('background', 'none');
            $('#addressFile.dropzone .dz-preview.dz-file-preview').text =  response.message;
            return file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-success");
        }
    };
```

The problem seems to be that the line:

```
 $('#addressFile.dropzone .dz-preview.dz-file-preview').text =  response.message;
```

Does seem to insert the text for me though alert(response.message) works fine.

Am I using the wrong event or fundamentally misunderstanding something?

Comment: You can use `.val(response.message);` or `.html(response.message);` insted of `.text `

Comment: thanks Paresh but that makes no difference

Comment: First you confirm that `#addressFile.dropzone .dz-preview.dz-file-preview` is a text field, div or any thing else?